# How to clear previous text in the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

using this script i can change the text in a div on click other text..i have four different text and a Div i want to change the text in div by clicking on other four text, its working properly but the problem is that i also show previous text when i click on next link, i want to clear previous text and show only new text..Please find the attach script and HTML and then help me , and let me know for further question.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#changeText1").click(function() {
            $("#textBox1").html("My text is changed1!");
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#changeText").click(function() {
            $("#textBox").html("My text is changed!");
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#changeText2").click(function() {
            $("#textBox2").html("My text is changed!2");
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#changeText3").click(function() {
            $("#textBox3").html("My text is changed!3");
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#changeText5").click(function() {
            $("#textBox5").html("My text is changed5!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this is html

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" id="changeText">inclusive</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="changeText2">Hotel</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="changeText3">Car</a></li>
    <li class="end"><a href="#" id="changeText5">Cruise</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs_cont">
    <div id="textBox3" style="color:#FFF"></div>
    <div id="textBox" style="color:#FFF"></div>
    <div id="textBox1" style="color:#FFF"></div>
    <div id="textBox2" style="color:#FFF"></div>
    <div id="textBox5" style="color:#FFF"></div>
</div>
<div id="textBox4" style="color:#FFF"></div>
```

Comment: You are always writing into a different `div`. If you would write into the same one it would work just fine, since `.html` replaces the content. Is there a reason you write into different `div`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing the element before setting the new text:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#changeText2").click(function() {
            $("#textBox2").empty().html("My text is changed!2");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants. `.html` already completely *replaces* the old content with the new content. Calling `.empty` beforehand is unnecessary. The outcome is the same.

Comment: @Dani: How can this be the solution if `.empty().html(...)` is exactly the same as `.html(...)`, which is what you had, and didn't work for you?

Comment: I'm stunned too. The OP's goal was probably different than what was actually asked..

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use separate `script` tag and `$(document).ready` for registering each click event. this can all be done once.

The better solution is to use one `div` for all tabs, but still if you want to keep all the divs, following code should help solve the issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#changeText1").click(function() {
        $('.tabs_cont div').empty();
        $("#textBox1").html("My text is changed1!");
    });

    $("#changeText").click(function() {
        $('.tabs_cont div').empty();
        $("#textBox").html("My text is changed!");
    });

    $("#changeText2").click(function() {
        $('.tabs_cont div').empty();
        $("#textBox2").html("My text is changed!2");
    });

    $("#changeText3").click(function() {
        $('.tabs_cont div').empty();
        $("#textBox3").html("My text is changed!3");
    });

    $("#changeText5").click(function() {
        $('.tabs_cont div').empty();
        $("#textBox5").html("My text is changed5!");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This will destroy any inner divs the OP will maybe add later to the first childs too. I'm not sure it's a safe solution.

Comment: Thanks Dear , i found the solution.. Its Perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#changeText1").click(function() {
            $("#textBox1").text("My text is changed1!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How does this solve the OP's problem, which is "hiding previously inserted text"?

Comment: use .html() to operate on containers having html elements.
use .text() to modify text of elements usually having separate open and closing tags

Comment: I agree that `.text` is more appropriate here, but it does not *solve* the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume there is no reason you have several divs. When you state that you only want to write to one div. So the problem is that you are writing to several divs instead of just one. Correct me if this isn't what you want.

I also removed your several script tags and textboxes, as they are unneccessary - at least in this example.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2aFTY/)

**Html:**

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" id="changeText">inclusive</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="changeText2">Hotel</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="changeText3">Car</a></li>
    <li class="end"><a href="#" id="changeText5">Cruise</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs_cont">
    <div id="textBox" ></div>
</div>
<div id="textBox4" style="color:#FFF"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#changeText").click(function() {
        $("#textBox").text("My text is changed!");
    });
    $("#changeText2").click(function() {
        $("#textBox").text("My text is changed!2");
    });
    $("#changeText3").click(function() {
        $("#textBox").text("My text is changed!3");
    });
    $("#changeText5").click(function() {
        $("#textBox").text("My text is changed5!");
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** Forgot to save the JSFiddle.. now that's just silly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you want. But please leave a comment and I'll update it. This is a smart-select structure, which cancels out all doublets you've made in your code.

Try to use the ready state only once, it's much cleaner:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#" id="changeText">inclusive</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="changeText2">Hotel</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="changeText3">Car</a></li>
        <li class="end"><a href="#" id="changeText5">Cruise</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs_cont" style="background-color: black;">
        <div id="textBox3" style="color:#FFF">3</div>
        <div id="textBox" style="color:#FFF">0</div>
        <div id="textBox1" style="color:#FFF">1</div>
        <div id="textBox2" style="color:#FFF">2</div>
        <div id="textBox5" style="color:#FFF">5</div>
    </div>
    <div id="textBox4" style="color:#FFF"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabs [id^="changeText"]').click(function(){
        var index = $(this).attr('id').split('changeText')[1];
        var backup_html = $('.tabs_cont #textBox' + index).html();

        // These are all the textboxes you want to match
        $('.tabs_cont [id^="textBox"]').html(''); // Empty them (or something else)

        // This HTML selector is the same as the one you clicked "changeText"
        $('.tabs_cont #textBox' + index).html('My text has changed: ' + (index == 0 ? 0 : index) + ': ' + $(this).html());
    });
});
```

`style="background-color: black;"` in the HTML was just for testing purposes :)

***UPDATE***

The new `main.js` per the OP's request:

```
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabs [id^="changeText"]').click(function(){
        var index = $(this).attr('id').split('changeText')[1];

        var new_html = 'My text has changed: ';

        switch(index) {
            case '':
                new_html += 'Text for 0';
                break;
            case '1':
                new_html += 'Text for 1';
                break;
            case '2':
                new_html += 'Text for 2';
                break;
            case '3':
                new_html += 'Text for 3';
                break;
            case '4':
                new_html += 'Text for 4';
                break;
            case '5':
                new_html += 'Text for 5';
                break;
        }

        // These are all the textboxes you want to match
        //$('.tabs_cont [id^="textBox"]').html(''); // Empty them (or something else)

        // This HTML selector is the same as the one you clicked "changeText"
        $('.tabs_cont #textBox' + index).html(new_html);
    });
});
```

**2nd variant, with cleaner map selector**

```
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabs [id^="changeText"]').click(function(){
        var index = $(this).attr('id').split('changeText')[1];

        var new_html = {
            '' : 'Text for 0',
            '1' : 'Text for 1',
            '2' : 'Text for 2',
            '3' : 'Text for 3',
            '4' : 'Text for 4',
            '5' : 'Text for 5',
        };

        // These are all the textboxes you want to match
        //$('.tabs_cont [id^="textBox"]').html(''); // Empty them (or something else)

        // This HTML selector is the same as the one you clicked "changeText"
        $('.tabs_cont #textBox' + index).html('My text has changed: ' + new_html[index]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Dear i like the script but i seems i not basically need this, i want to write four paragraph in four button the given code was just the example can you please upgrade the script i want to to write four different paragraph in 1 div using four different links. :)

Comment: Updated the answer Dani. Hope it's what you're looking for. Good luck!